# CRM 2011 Active entities on parent

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have been trying for ages to solve a problem but I don't know JavaScript so i'm chasing my tail around the Internet.

I have inherited a JavaScript file which is supposed to fire when a plan is made on an account. Each account can have multiple plans but only 1 active one at a time. That means that when you create a new one, you should only be able if all others are deactivated. The code we have now (see below) only looks for the existence of a plan regardless of its state. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

```
checkActiveADP = function()
{
    // check if there is a key account populated
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_keyaccountid").getValue() != null && Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1)
    {
        // get the id of the parent account of the account plan
        var keyaccountid = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_keyaccountid").getValue()[0].id;

        if (keyaccountid != null)
        {
            // build query to get all the account plans for the current parent account - if any
            var filter = "/New_accountplanSet()?$filter=new_keyaccountid/Id eq guid'" + keyaccountid + "'";             
            var retrievedMultiple = CCrm.JSCore.RetrieveMultipleRequest(filter);                        

            if (retrievedMultiple.results.length >=1) 
            {
                alert("Active ADP already exists, please update that one or deactivate before creating a new one");                             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any result back for your query? try `alert(retrievedMultiple.results.length);`

Comment: When that runs and there are deactivated plans linked to the parent account it throws up the message and wont let you save a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the active state filter (`StateCode/Value eq 0`) to the **OData** `filter` variable, as follows:

```
        var filter = "/New_accountplanSet()?$filter=new_keyaccountid/Id eq guid'" + keyaccountid + "' and StateCode/Value eq 0";
        var retrievedMultiple = CCrm.JSCore.RetrieveMultipleRequest(filter);

        if (retrievedMultiple.results.length >= 1)
        {
            alert("Active ADP already exists, please update that one or deactivate before creating a new one");
        }
```

The result will include only the active account plans records, if any.

Answer (score 0):

`retrievedMultiple.results` is an array.  You'll need to do a for loop over the items, checking to see if their status is active.

Comment: Thank's very much, like I say I don't know JavaScript but at least I have a place to start now

Comment: @Powell21 Do you have any programming background?

Comment: I'm an SQL Developer, I have just been handed this

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like below: 
Add an else condition after `retrievedMultiple != null || retrievedMultiple.results != null` to verify that there is nothing wrong with your query.

```
checkActiveADP = function()
{
    // check if there is a key account populated
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_keyaccountid").getValue() != null && Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1)
    {
        // get the id of the parent account of the account plan
        var keyaccountid = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_keyaccountid").getValue()[0].id;

        if (keyaccountid != null)
        {
            // build query to get all the account plans for the current parent account - if any
            var filter = "/New_accountplanSet()?$filter=new_keyaccountid/Id eq guid'" + keyaccountid + "'";             
            var retrievedMultiple = CCrm.JSCore.RetrieveMultipleRequest(filter);                        

            if (retrievedMultiple != null || retrievedMultiple.results != null) 
            {
               for(var i = 0;i<retrievedMultiple.results.length; i++)
               {
                   if(retrievedMultiple.results[i]["statecode"] == 0)
                   {
                       alert("Active ADP already exists, please update that one or deactivate before creating a new one");
                   }
               }                            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has made it possible for you to have multiple active account plans. Thank's for the help guys, I don't expect you to do this for me but I am completely at sea with JS